# Can extensions contribute a custom task in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VS Code extension. I want to contribute a Task to the user's workspace, without the user having to configure it (ideally conditionally, depending on the contents of the workspace), and I probably also need a custom `problemMatcher`.

Does VS Code expose an API to do so? Or should I be writing my own command instead of a task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an API for contributing tasks was introduced in VSCode 1.14 (June 2017). The entry point for it is the `registerTaskProvider()` method found in the [`vscode.tasks` namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_tasks). For a usage example, check out the [`task-provider-sample`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/task-provider-sample/src/extension.ts) found in `vscode-extension-samples`.