# How to create default tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I found how to create tasks for a project but these tasks are not saved from a project to another.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to create default tasks that would be accessible to every new project ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an unresolved feature request for allowing tasks to be shared across projects:

- [Shared configuration (tasks/settings) (#1435)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1435)

In the meantime, it's possible to work around this by creating a custom extension using the task provider API:

- [Extension API - Task Provider - Build Task example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135876/extension-api-task-provider-build-task-example/55140893)
- [Can extensions contribute a custom task in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157186/can-extensions-contribute-a-custom-task-in-vs-code)